# How to make/use custom circle?

Tags: android, xml, layout, user-interface, android-view

I need a circle object as follows :
[image: circle]

The name and count extracts info from a DB and displays it for each circle. 
The circle needs to be clickable so I'm thinking of extending the Button class.

What do I do in the onDraw and onMeasure methods to create this? Also once created, how do I use this class? How can I call this component to be displayed in my screen with other component views?

EDIT: I have read many posts and some tutorials and none have been too helpful for "customized views"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need extend the button class to do this.

If I were you I probably wouldn't even make a custom View, I would use a LinearLayout with 2 TextViews in it. And the background on the linear layout I would set to a png of the circle.

something like this would be the xml;

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/circle"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/circleLyt">

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/nameTxt"
 />

<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/countTxt"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure to put circle.png into your `drawable` folder.
You can gain references to all of these Views with `findViewById();` So once you have references to the TextViews you can set the text to whatever you need. And with the LinearLayout reference you can set a click listener on it the exact same way as you would for a Button.

something like this would work:

```
mCircleView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.circleLyt);
mCircleView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v){
        //do some stuff!
    }
});
```

You could even make this layout as its own xml file and use an Adapter to be able to fill some other structure with these circles like a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html) perhaps. You'd just need to inflate the Views and populate the text inside your Adapters getView() method.

Comment: Potential problem with doing it this way is that the layout will wrap to it's content - the TextViews - without necessarily staying square, creating a flattened oval instead of a circle. Also, it would be possible to set clickable="true" and onClick="clickedFunction" as an alternative to programatically creating an OnClickListener.

Comment: True on both points. Making the png file into a 9-patch can solve the most of the potential issues. Alternatively a static width and height could be given to the LinearLayout. And yes onClick() will work that way too. I just learned with the inner classes and still do it because it's quicker to debug for me.

Comment: The reason i wanted a custom view is that I hope to create 6 of these circles in my code programmatically. Could I do this with this xml layout? Also I'm suppose to scale the size of the circle according to fit 6 into the screen size...how can I do this in xml if I just set an image?

Comment: yes you could still do that. Use a LayoutInflator (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html) to build a java object from the xml layout and then add it to your parent layout.

Comment: sorry can you elaborate on how I can have android draw a circle (i'm thinking the canvas.drawCircle() method) as the boundary of this view instead of using a circle.png resource?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you don't need a custom view to achieve this job. Using a TextView with a `background` of circle is enough.

If a simple circle, refer to [drawable resource documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) for detail; or you can create your custom drawable (that you can draw on canvas) and supply it as backgroundDrawable.

Comment: could u elaborate on the custom drawable more? I'd like to scale this circle to fit 6 on screen, and I'd rather use the android's draw feature than to supply a bitmap. I think that'll look more crisp.